# Aggregating Data in Google Sheets via Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 100+ rows that are updated daily via import range. My objective is to aggregate user's key results from multiple cells into one single cell per user. Currently I have to update my column "Key Results Aggerated" manually by copying and pasting since my formula doesn't work since it aggregates info incorrectly. Thanks in advance.

Current formula in Cell E1:

```
={"Key Results Aggerated";MAP(A2:A,D2:D,LAMBDA(aval,dval,IF(aval="","", TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,dval:INDEX(D:D,ROW(dval)+IFNA(XMATCH("*",INDEX(A:A,ROW(aval)+1):INDEX(A:A, ROWS(D:D))),ROWS(A:A))-1)))))}
```

[Pic: Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpY0L.png)

[Pic: Results I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgUCO.png)

[Google Spreadsheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13RrMdcrRKJX6aofpsfdHAn-NW2pWWqKsjiieti-sqoQ/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen just some minutes ago your previous question. Add a two in XMATCH for allowing wildcards:

```
={"Key Results Aggerated";MAP(A2:A,D2:D,LAMBDA(aval,dval,IF(aval="","", TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,dval:INDEX(D:D,ROW(dval)+IFNA(XMATCH("*",INDEX(A:A,ROW(aval)+1):INDEX(A:A, ROWS(D:D)),2),ROWS(A:A))-1)))))}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
={"Key Results Aggregated";INDEX(BYROW(IF(LEN(C2:C),COUNTIFS(ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C),C2:C,"<>"),),LAMBDA(z,IF(z="",,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,IFNA(FILTER(D2:D,SCAN(,IF(LEN(C2:C),1,),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))=z)))))))}
```

- 

[image]